# Getting coordinates of a JTextField in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout

I've added a `JTextField` in a `JFrame` using the `BorderLayout`.
Now I want to know the location of the `JTextField`.

I used `getX()` and `getLocation()`, but both gives me `0`, which is not the right answer.
So how do I get that location?

Comment: Why do you want that information?  Or perhaps, what functionality are you trying to offer the end user (and not forgetting that the end user can **see** where the `JTextField` is located, they should not need to be told)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `getLocation()` in a component (the `JTextField`) should return its coordinates **relative** to the parent container (in the example below, the `JFrame`).

**Note**: You will have to *do the layout* in the container (`JFrame`) **before** getting the coordinates.
Doing the layout is acomplished by simply showing it.

**Example**:

```
JFrame fr = new JFrame("Testing window");
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
fr.add(tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);

fr.setVisible(true); //show the JFrame

Point p = tf.getLocation(); //get the coordinates
```

Comment: Bad example, you should not hardcode "Center" for a BorderLayout constraint.

Comment: @camickr You're right. I was only trying to make things simpler. Anyway, this is not the focus of the example.

Comment: @user3300710 because it's a constant. You're expected to reference it directly: `BorderLayout.CENTER`. That way it always works no matter what the actual constant value is.

Comment: @user3300710, the original code was `fr.add(tf, "CENTER")`, so my comment was that you should not hardcode "CENTER". The code was updated and now uses `BorderLayout.CENTER`, which is the way it should be coded for the reason given above.

Answer (score 2):

The getLocation() method gives the location of the component relative to its parent in this case the content pane, so the location may in fact be 0. Also you can't invoke the method until the frame is visible.

If you want the location relative to the frame then you need to use

```
SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...);
```